# How to redirect www.example.com to example.com in route53 aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-route53

I have setup record in route53 for example.com to point to my cloudfront distribution(serves all the static files). I want browser to redirect to example.com if user goes to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I could point www to same cloudfront distribution, but then browser treats both these domains as seperate sites. They use different local browser cache and all. I want them to use same local cache.

Comment: I don't understand if `www.example.com` is redirected to `example.com` how browser is having local cache of `www.example.com` ? also can you provide in the question what is the role of `cloudfront`? is it serving your SPA or resources?

Comment: Currently both www.example.com and example.com points to xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net and both have seperate local cache in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself after lot of research. Point www to a s3 endpoint configured to redirect to example.com. Refer this [article](https://www.vivekmchawla.com/how-to-set-up-url-forwarding-in-aws-using-only-route-53-and-s3/) for more info.
Also, I am now using google domains instead of route 53 because it has inbuilt option to redirect subdomain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be _helpful_, but avoid making it _necessary_ to click on them as much as possible.